# Why creating an array consumes a way more memory compare with DOMDocument?

Tags: php, xml, dom

I was wondering today how much memory I lose on handling DOMDocument instead of an ordinary array and it surprised me. Tests show that DOM is more efficient.
The test was simple: small initialization, get some data from SOAP and put it
1. in array 2. in DOM and all these exercises measured with memory_get_usage (false and true respectively)
Results are below:

1. Array

```
1:start local 362,204 system 524,288
2:init  local 362,472 system 524,288
3:soap  local 4,099,776 system 4,718,592
3:dom   local 4,101,784 system 4,718,592
```

1. DOM

```
1:start local 362,204 system 524,288
2:init  local 362,468 system 524,288
3:soap  local 4,099,776 system 4,718,592
3:array local 6,118,164 system 6,553,600
```

Can anyone tell me why arrays are much more memory expensive?

How can 140kb (I measured it with strlen of only attribute values) of data (generally text) fits in 4,101,784 - 4,099,776 = 2008 bytes.
I just don't get it.

Comment: Wouldn't this be better placed on StackOverflow?

Answer (score 0):

Note that `memory_get_usage` only tells you how much memory did the PHP process allocate from system memory. Most probably PHP allocates system memory in big chunks to improve speed: asking OS to allocate small pieces (e.g. 140 kbytes) is too slow. Then the pre-allocated system memory is allocated internally inside the PHP process: it maintains its own pool of free memory and its own used memory graph. When you create a smallish structure inside PHP, it just marks some part of its internal memory pool as used, but you can't see this from the outside.

The 2008 bytes is probably some overhead needed by internal memory allocator.

The number 4,718,592 is identical in both cases and is 0x480000, or exactly 1152 4kb memory pages; it's no coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the DOMDocument implementation, you'll see that they dont store the hole thing in one big array, rather they have a Object Structure where data is stored in variables and some of them are arrays ([DOMDocument implementation](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/6446.html)). Altough this is more memory efficient because the use of pointers, its slower.

Arrays are much faster but they required one big piece of memory all at once so if you try to model a hirearchy with arrays, you'll end up with a big matrix, that you must have all in memory, witch is faster but more expensive in memory terms.

Answer (score 0):

Adding invocation of `ps --pid $pid --no-headers -orss` to output shows the real process memory usage. Seems that memory_get_usage function shows memory statistics with some assumption.

```
1:start  local 366,656 system 524,288 ps 5,352 kb  
2:init   local 367,168 system 524,288 ps 5,432 kb  
3:soap   local 5,007,656 system 5,505,024 ps 13,352 kb  
3:array  local 6,122,788 system 6,553,600 ps 13,492 kb
```

```
1:start  local 409,628 system 524,288 ps 5,356 kb
2:init   local 409,628 system 524,288 ps 5,436 kb
3:soap   local 5,011,328 system 5,505,024 ps 13,348 kb
3:dom    local 5,011,328 system 5,505,024 ps 13,592 kb
```